# unable to import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration [libgdx]

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to resize the default screen of my desktop aplication in libgdx, but when i import this package, appear that the package doesnt exists.
Could anyone help me?
or anyone knows another way to do that?
Thansks for your attention :D.

Answer (score 0):

check your build.gradle file and always use libgdx project set up app to create a libgdx peoject. It will help you to add all the needed jars.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html